# Story with quote about oral sex and eyelashes, possibly Heinlein

Tags: story-identification, books, robert-a-heinlein, quotes

Maybe fifteen years ago I read a story in which a character says, of the act of performing oral sex on a woman, that *if your eyelashes don’t get wet, you’re doing it wrong*—or words to that effect.

In the intervening years I’ve paraphrased these words in casual company, always attributing them to Robert A. Heinlein. I’ve always been sure it was Heinlein, but I could never remember which story it was. Lately, however, I’ve begun to doubt myself for the simple reason that google as I might, I can’t find any reference to this quote.

I’ve read most of Heinlein’s novels (the few I’ve missed are all for younger readers, I think) and a couple of his short story collections, so I can’t really narrow it down. It would seem to fit best among his later works. I’m open to the possibility that it wasn’t Heinlein after all, but I’m pretty sure it was sci-fi, since that’s most of what I read. I do know it was at least ten years ago.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it have been from one of the 'Legacy of Aldenata'  alien invasion series by John Ringo? Maybe said by Callie?

Comment: To the close voters: OP being "pretty sure it was sci-fi since that’s most of what [they] read" should be enough to make this on topic.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not Heinlein. The only reference I can find in his works is in To Sail Beyond The Sunset where there are a couple of passing references to *cunnilingus* but no mention of eyelashes.

Comment: I don't recognize this quote at all, and I think I've read everything.

Comment: @Danny3414 I don’t think I’ve read that. Thanks, though!

Comment: I'm a big Heinlein fan, and I don't think this is Heinlein.

Comment: I can't pin it down but I believe this is an alteration of a Heinlein quote that is only vaguely similar in its overall sentiment but entirely different in the particulars, something about properly enjoying making love or some such.  I will try to recall.